# Hi Im planning to host a local server using port-forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I successfully setup the port-forwarding in my router(Tp-link) I opened the port

```
Game: Battle Realms-Ubisoft - PC
TCP:
UDP: 7174,7175,7177
```

The problem that I countered is

```
1st player can joined in my Direct IP server
2nd player can't join(it seems blocked or somethings wrong or limit)
```

is this on the port-forwarding(limit) or its on my game?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you should forward TCP ports too.

Comment: I did but still doesnt work.